# Query clustering and partitioning in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I want to create a clustered table with events that would help me spend less time and processed rows reading it.
What is the point of the table. I'm getting event data from GA4 and I'm wasting too many processed rows reading it. Based on this problem, I want to create a new clustered table that will store the fields I need.
I have fields for the date and time when the user did a certain action in the application and other fields related to it. Basically, I will need data from this table about the date and time of execution of a certain event by certain users, the number of events executed in general by user or a certain date, etc.

I've been reading a lot about clustering and partitioning, but I thought I'd ask the community what fields would be more correct to create this partitioning and clustering based on?
I am attaching my own code below
Thank you!)
`

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE
  chasto-prod.analytics_324473216.EventAnalytics
PARTITION BY
  date
CLUSTER BY
  event_name AS
SELECT
  CAST(FORMAT_DATE('%Y-%m-%d', PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d', event_date)) AS Date) AS date,
  CAST(FORMAT_TIME('%T', TIME(TIMESTAMP_MICROS(event_timestamp))) AS Time) AS time,
  event_name,
  device.category,
  device.mobile_brand_name,
  device.mobile_model_name,
  device.operating_system,
  geo.continent,
  geo.country,
  geo.city,
  traffic_source.name,
  traffic_source.medium,
  traffic_source.source,
  platform,
  CASE
    WHEN K.value.string_value IS NULL THEN CAST(K.value.int_value AS string)
  ELSE
  K.value.string_value
END
  AS UserID
FROM
  `chasto-prod.analytics_324473216.events_*`,
  UNNEST(event_params) AS K
WHERE
  K.key='user_id'
```

`

Answer (score 0):

Your use case seems to be focused on dates and users, so it would make sense to design the partition by date and clustering by user and event type.

Remember that clustering means that data is stored colocated, so it will be faster and more efficient if you are filtering or grouping by user and event.

According to the docs:

*The order of clustered columns affects query performance. To benefit from clustering, the query filter order must match the clustered column order and must include at least the first clustered column.*

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/clustered-tables#cluster_column_ordering

Also remember that the clustering order is important when writing queries.

*To optimize your clustering results, you must filter from clustered columns in order starting from the first clustered column.*